# postgres check constraint on length of elements in text[]

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Is there a possibility to add a check constraint to ensure the length of the elements in a text[] in postgres?

I want each element to have a length of 2 characters (country iso code).

Usecase: it's a filter. The entity saved in that row should only be active in the countries included in that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but ugly since you'd need a `2 = ALL (SELECT length(value) FROM unnest(arr))` subquery which you'd have to place in an `immutable` helper function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74442663/1048572).

Instead, why not just switch from an array of `text` to the appropriate [character type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html): `character(2)[]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the character(2) hint!

Comment: Hmm, when an element is longer, it's fine (error), but when the element is shorter it is silently filled with whitespace characters. Any idea how to recognize too short elements?

Comment: oh right, I forgot about the space-padding, that's annoying here. I guess you should either go with a `varchar(2)` and use the length restriction, or you use `char(2)` and add an extra check constraint that checks for valid characters (e.g. `array_to_string(arr, '') ~ '^[a-z]+$'`)